# Problems with Facebook login on localhost

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii, facebook-login

I'm using [Yii eauth](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth) plugin for logging into social networks and it works on my prod server. But I'm having problem making it work on my local developer machine.

I don't user http://localhost, but http://my-domain.com

I've created a FB called MyApp LOCAL, but I'm unsure what to add in `App Domains` and `Site URL`.

[image]

When I login, the FB pop-up dialogue URL looks like this:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=12345678901515987&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-domain.com%2Flogin%3Fservice%3Dfacebook&scope=email,%20public_profile,%20user_friends&response_type=code`

But nothing happens and I'm just redirected back to my login page.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**
My JS code for localhost is currently:
(This is placed in the header)

```
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '12345678901515987',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.3'
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

The only additional JS code I can find in my source code (generated by Yii eauth) is this:

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".auth-service.facebook a").eauth({"popup":{"width":585,"height":290},"id":"facebook"});

});
/*]]>*/
```

Comment: please post your JS code to effect the login.

Comment: The code you posted will tell you what to do to connect to FB, not what to do after you get a response to the auth attempt. Please track and add this.

Comment: I just found one more line of code generated by Yii eauth.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, that works fine on my localhost.

You will see in the code a line :

window.location.href = "/webuser/account/fblogin";

The url "*/webuser/account/fblogin*" is a controller action the creates a user session and configures the user as logged in

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '1234567890', // replace your app id here
            channelUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/your_fb_url',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };
    (function(d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
    function FBLogin() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                window.location.href = "/webuser/account/fblogin";
            }
        }, {scope: 'email,publish_actions,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history'});
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#login-facebook').click(function(event){
             event.preventDefault()
             FBLogin();
             return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @crafter. How old is your code? Because it looks very different from mine. (see code added in my question)

Comment: OK, I just see now that you are using eauth. Sorry I missed that point, My code uses the FB JS API. I'll delete my answer soon as it does not answer your question directly. However. I'm sure the generated code looks something like what  Facebook requires at the end of the day. Happy hunting.